# Insert list of unique values in data-validation-list (without using a helper column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |     A      |        B       |
--|------------|----------------|--
1 | Product A  |   Product A    |
2 | Product A  |   Product B    |
3 | Product B  |   Product C    |
4 |            |   Product D    |
5 | Product C  |                |
6 | Product C  |                |
7 | Product C  |                |
8 | Product D  |                |
```

---

In the data-validation from Excel I want to create a list of the **unique values** from `Column A` and **ignore the empty values**. 
Therefore, I built a helper column in `Column B` in which I make the list in `Column A` unique using this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A8,A1:A8<>""))
```

All this works perfectly.

---

However, I would prefer a solution without the helper `Column B`. 
Therefore, I tried to enter the formula above into the data-validation in Excel:

[image]

Afterwards, Excel gives me this message:`the source currently evaluates to an error`.

How can I make the data-validation menu work without using a Helper Column?

Comment: you can simplify your formula using `TOCOL` as follows: `UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A8,1))`, but it doesn't solve your problem. I don't think you can do it without a helper column. Usually I create a helper tab and hide it for such kind of scenario, like sorting the dropdown list, etc. As per my understanding data validation doesn't work with dynamic array formula like you have. In some scenario it can be circumvent using `INDIRECT` function but it works only with ranges not arrays.

Comment: Like David Leal says you need the helper to be able to reference the range. You can than refer to it like `='Sheet1'!$B$1#`

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use VBA, here is a solution which doesn't require a helper column. Just set the validationSourceRange and validatedCell variables to whatever you want and run the updateValidation sub.

The updateValidation could be setup to run every time the sheet recalculates or every time the contents of the source range change as well.

```vb
Sub updateValidation()
    Dim validationSourceRange As Range, validatedCell As Range
    
    'set the following two variables as you need
    Set validationSourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
    Set validatedCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    
    validatedCell.Validation.Delete
    
    Dim listString As String
    listString = stringFromCollection(uniqueValuesFromColumn(validationSourceRange), ",")
    
    validatedCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=listString
End Sub

Function uniqueValuesFromColumn(ByVal rng As Range, Optional ByVal colNum As Integer = 1) As Collection
    Set uniqueValuesFromColumn = New Collection
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = rng
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Dim val As String
        val = arr(i, colNum)
        On Error Resume Next
            If val <> "" Then uniqueValuesFromColumn.Add val, val
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Function

Function stringFromCollection(ByVal col As Collection, ByVal separator As String) As String
    Dim val As Variant
    For Each val In col
        stringFromCollection = stringFromCollection & val & separator
    Next val
    stringFromCollection = Left(stringFromCollection, Len(stringFromCollection) - Len(separator))
End Function
```